# How to format post title text in 2 lines using css

Tags: posts, css

I have babynames website and my post titles are very large.

Post Title: Abdal-lafif – عبد الطیف Meaning in English and Urdu

I want *Meaning in English and Urdu* will display with line break i.e 2nd line
This is my current post screenshot

[image]

If i add line break in post title it will effect my seo. Can someone please suggest how can I achieve this like the screenshot below with CSS ?

[image]

Comment: Not possible with just CSS, changing the html is a must, and if you're going to why not have an element for each half

Answer (score 0):

Add line break in post title and set CSS rule `white-space: pre-wrap;` for it.

Details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space